# Dynamic Client Side Throttling inside a C# Service

Tags: c#, async-await, httprequest, throttling

I have a client application that will get a large number of jobs to run, on the order of 10k, and foreach will make an http request to a web api. Each job is semi long running and unpredictable 7-90s response times.

I am trying to minimize the total time for all jobs. I notice that if I make too many requests at once, response times drastically increase because the server is essentially being DoSed. This is bringing the total for all jobs way up. I have been using `SemaphoreSlim` to statically set the order of parallelism but need to find a way to dynamically adjust based on current response times to get the lowest response times overall. Here is the code I have been using.

```
List<Task<DataTable>> tasks = new List<Task<DataTable>>();
SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(40, 300);
foreach (DataRow entry in newEntries.Rows)
{
    await throttler.WaitAsync();

    tasks.Add(Task<DataTable>.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            return RunRequest(entry); //Http requests and other logic is done here
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    }
    ));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

I know that `throttler.Release();` can be passed different numbers to increase the total number of outstanding request at one time and calling `Wait()` without `Release()` will subtract from the count.

I believe that need to keep a some sort of rolling average of response times. Using the rolling average some how determine how much to increase/decrease the total number of outstanding requests being allowed. I am not sure if this is the right direction or not.

**Question**
Given the information above, how can I keep the total number of outstanding requests at a level to have the minimum time spent for all jobs.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @i3arnon Added a more clear question summary.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<DataTable> dataTables = new List<DataTable>();

Parallel.ForEach(newEntries.AsEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, row => {
   var request = RunRequest(row);
   lock(dataTables)
   {
        dataTables.Add(request);
   }
});
```

Now you can adjust the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`  //I wasn't understanding that you wanted to have this dynamically changed as the tasks were running.

I'll tell you from past experience when trying to allow users to change the amount of running threads when they are in process using a Semaphore, I wanted to jump in front of a moving truck.  This was back before TPL.

Create a list of unstarted tasks.  Start the number of tasks that you want, like 5 to start. Each task can return a duration from start to finish so you can use it to define your throttle logic.  Now just loop the tasks with waitany as the block.

```
var runningTasks = 5;
//for loop to start 5 tasks.

while (taskList.count > 0)
{
    var indexer = Task.WaitAny(taskList);
    var myTask = taskList[indexer];
    taskList.RemoveAt(indexer);
    InterLocker.Decrement(ref runningTasks);
    var durationResult = myTask.Result();
    //do logic to determine if you need to start more.
    //when you start another use InterLocker.Increment(ref runningTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I adjust MaxDegreeOfParallelism while running inside the loop? Also I am trying to figure out what criteria and when to adjust given my situation.

Comment: I believe I have the ability to adjust the running count in my code above. I am more looking for the logic as to how to throttle, and on what metrics, if that makes sense.

Comment: Also your first block of code doesn't compile without changing ParallelOptions { instead of ( and then .Rows to something like AsEnumerable().